how can i check that the jwt is expired or not on the frontend, how the real world websites check it on frontend
Actually i want my jwt to get expired after a day but the problem is, I can't use the verify function on frontend, so i decided to store another field as expiry_date which will store the current date or time of the system and when user comes another time on my website, since it will check the jwt from cookie and there it will check for expiry by comparing the current date and time with the jwt's and if its difference is more than 1 day then it will logout the user, but the problem is that what if user changes the date and time of the system in that case what can we do.
I want the solution of how the real world website deals with this problem of checking the jwt on frontend

This is one long sentence. Split your questions into sub parts, so that it is easier to read and comprehend.
